# Why isn't this reflecting in the front-end?

Tags: wordpress

```
<a href="?page=gmgt_workouttype&tab=workouttypelist" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'workouttypelist' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">
                        <?php echo '<span class="dashicons dashicons-menu"></span> '.__('Workout Log', 'gym_mgt'); ?></a>
```

Now, I want to change the Workout Log to Logs.
However, this isn't reflecting in front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the browser cache and refresh.